# iOS 6 - Issue with AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, ios6, avspeechsynthesizer

Why do I get an error when I run it on **iOS6** though I checked for `AVSpeechSynthesizer`? I am aware that AVSpeechSynthesizer is only available in iOS7

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"AVSpeechSynthesizer")) {

      AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
      AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Just what do you think you're doing, Dave?"];
      utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate; // Tell it to me slowly
      [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];

}
```

Comment: @import AVFoundation;

Answer (score 2):

I see a similar issue with roughly the same code.  The problem on iOS6 is that `AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumRate` doesn't exist and a dynamic link error is generated when the code is loaded.  Comment that line out and the code does actually run on iOS6 but doesn't say anything.  I guess it must be that the AV speech code is done differently to other interfaces and you'll need to find another way to decide if it is iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

Because AVSpeechSynthesizer is only for iOS 7! In apple developers page for AVSpeechSynthesizer Class Reference:

`Availability: Available in iOS 7.0 and later.`

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it's only available in 7, how to have backward compatability. if (NSClassFromString(@"AVSpeechSynthesizer")) condition is for version check.But still fails